# How to move the page layout from one org to another?

Tags: custom-object, page-layout, mavensmate

Is there a way to move the page layout from one org to another org?... I find it very hard to re-create entire page layout again after I moved my objects from one org to another org and I'm sure there is way to handle this scenario.

here is the selected metadata MM

[image]

Comment: I'm using MM to move objects and not come across moving page layout

Comment: You can do it with eclipse. I don't use MM, so can't tell you what your issue is. Most likely you've not selected the correct type of metadata to be able to move the pages.

Comment: Are you trying to move it from one org to another related org (e.g sandbox to Prod) or between 2 unrelated Orgs?

Comment: its related orgs, sandbox to test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you selected the Layout component type on the Advanced Tab? It looks like your Project Metadata is showing only the 7 types that are selected by Default. Try selecting Layout on the Advanced Tab and use the Refresh link on Project Metadata to pull in the Layouts.

Comment: Got it, never thought of going through :)